# django eventstream - only empty data

Tags: django, django-channels

I installed and followed the guide from the [git](https://github.com/fanout/django-eventstream/), but I hit a wall once I try to execute a `send_message()` call using the shell.

I rewrote the asgi.py:

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": URLRouter([
        path("msgs/", AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(django_eventstream.routing.urlpatterns)), { "format-channels": ["test"] }),
        re_path(r"", get_asgi_application()),
    ]),
})
```

and I created the entries in urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [path("msgs/", include(django_eventstream.urls), {'format-channels': ["test"]})]
```

I also added the static ressources to my static directory and I can access them on any page that includes my `base.html`. But when I open the local msgs channel at `127.0.0.1\msgs\` I only see:

[image]

When opening a shell in a second terminal and using `send_event("test", "message", {"text": "hello"})` I see no indication whatsoever that anything is sent out to the frontend. Also the JS sample code from the repo fetches nothing on the main page when sending out data in a loop with starting django (using the fantastic scheduler huey here):

```
@periodic_task(crontab(minute = "*/1"))
def test():
    send_event('test', 'message', {'text': 'hello world'})
    print("hello world...")
```

I see the output of `print()` but not the result of `send_message()` on the frontend. Also, there is no implication that my scheduled or manually run `send_message()` actions result in anything on the `\msgs\` channel - the timing does not fit, it looks more like this is just regularly printing keep-alive with no data in it.

The JS console output on the frontend:

```
var es = new ReconnectingEventSource('/msgs/');

es.addEventListener('message', function (e) {console.log(e.data);}, false);
es.addEventListener('stream-reset', function (e) {}, false);
```

output for `es`:

```
s {CONNECTING: 0, OPEN: 1, CLOSED: 2, _configuration: undefined, withCredentials: false, …}
```

Comment: Have you been able to solve this?

Comment: unfortunately not. I think that the devs are trying to see how they integrate with the new async architecture of Django > 4.